# How to create a simple slideshow for images of different sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I am looking for a slider for web applications that supports the display of pictures of different sizes.

I have seen nivo slider, but i need a free solution. I also tried colorbox but i want it to load in the page not another div.

I want something that behaves like facebook when it comes to showing images, but behaving has a slideshow.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [jQuery cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/). Look at [this example](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/diff.html) to see different image sizes in action.

Answer (score 0):

Probably now the most common method, which supports many features you may want to add to your slider, is the [Bootstrap 3 Carousel](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Bootstrap Carousel will automatically slide between images, also allowing the user to manually slide through images and can resize to given image sizes or be forced to stay the same size with a bit of CSS tweaking.

EDIT: They have working examples at http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples.

Comment: Do you have any example working just for the caroussel, in here they don't do a presentation for beginners that they can use and alter easily.